Oauth2client StorageByKeyName deprecations Google App Engine
I'm working on an upgrade from python 2 to python 3.
The app uses oauth2client.StorageByKeyName
oauth2client was deprecated.
Is there a recommended upgrade path?

oauth2client is deprecated and you should migrate to the Google APIs Client Library for Python.
Recommended upgrade path:

Install google-api-python-client.

Replace oauth2client imports with googleapiclient.discovery.

Migrate storage:

Use StorageCredentialStore for Google Cloud Storage.

Use FileStorage for a JSON file.



Update your code to use the new API client methods. Refer to the Google APIs Client Library documentation for details.


Reference:

Google APIs Client Library


What replaces StorageByKeyName?

There isn't a direct replacement for oauth2client.StorageByKeyName in the Google APIs Client Library for Python. However, you can achieve similar functionality. Use the StorageCredentialStore class from googleapiclient.discovery to manage them. This approach is secure and scalable, but it requires setting up Google Cloud Storage. Check this documentation about StorageCredentialStore for reference.

Thanks. it sounds like the best path is to import StorageByKeyName  into the project
